# How to remove implied ids from group in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to remove **`implied ids`** of **purchase user group**.
This is actual group in purchase order

```xml
<record id="group_purchase_manager" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Manager</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_purchase_management"/>
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_purchase_user'))]"/>
    <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
</record>
```

Then I am trying to remove implied of the group in my custom module

```xml
<record id="purchase.group_purchase_manager" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Manager</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_purchase_management"/>
    <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
</record>
```

I also tries another

```xml
<record id="purchase.group_purchase_manager" model="res.groups">
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="False"/>
</record>
```

unfortunately both will not work.

I checked the groups of **purchases/Manger** in UI but the inherited group **purchases/User** still there.

How to remove **implied ids** from purchase manager group??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try with following code.

```xml
<record id="purchase.group_purchase_manager" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Manager</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_purchase_management"/>
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('purchase.group_purchase_user'))]"/>
    <field name="users" eval="[(3, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
</record>
```

With help of *3,* we will cut/delete relationship between two objects without delete target ID *(ref('base.user_root'))*.

I haven't tested it.

Comment: Odedra:Thanks,It works perfectly,3 is the best option.thanks for sharing the important information