# How to override an existing group of res.groups model in Odoo12?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-12

I need to override an existing group in a custom module and change just it's `implied_ids` field in another custom module. I tried to use the same code in my module with the changes in `implied_ids` but I had bellow error.  Then I tried to use inherit_id field but is raised duplicate id error again. Bellow is the original group in a custom module:

```
<record id="group_hms_jr_doctor" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">Jr Doctor</field>
            <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_hms"/>
            <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('acs_hms.group_hms_nurse')),(4, ref('acs_hms.group_hms_receptionist'))]"/>
            <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root')), (4, ref('base.user_admin'))]"/>
        </record>
```

and I want to just remove `(4, ref('acs_hms.group_hms_receptionist'))` section from it. I tried bellow code, but this errors raises.

```
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "duplicate key value violates unique constraint "res_groups_name_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (category_id, name)=(68, Jr Doctor) already exists.
" while parsing /home/ibrahim/workspace/odoo/hms/nl_hms/security/security.xml:5, near
<record id="group_hms_jr_doctor_inherited" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Jr Doctor</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="acs_hms.group_hms_jr_doctor"/>
        <field name="category_id" ref="acs_hms.module_category_hms"/>
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('acs_hms.group_hms_nurse'))]"/>
        <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root')), (4, ref('base.user_admin'))]"/>
    </record>
```

How can I override any existing groups and changes it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To update an existing records you should give the full XML-ID of that records (include the name of app), and to remove an item from many2many field use `3 command`, this will remove the item from `x2many` field but  doesn't delete it from the database:

```
<record id="acs_hms.group_hms_jr_doctor" model="res.groups">
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(3, ref('acs_hms.group_hms_receptionist'))]"/>
</group>
```

what will happen here is Odoo will call `write` on `res.groups` and  `4` command is used to add record to `x2many` field this will not effect the field at all because the record all ready exist.

Comment: I applied above changes but still no effect, also I found this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340375/how-to-remove-implied-ids-from-group-in-odoo]. This solution suggests something different. Which one is correct? in my case non of them work.

Comment: Check if the file is in data in odoo manifest, check if the xml file that loads the data in the original app use no update,  if so I will edit my answer to force the Update on the record

Comment: Actually this code was working but there was something wrong with the sequence of my modules. I find that with lots of debugging. The sequence of depends on menifiest files was causing recalling the original modle and overriding the changes again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the other custom module as dependency in your custom module and then just "override" the values in need by using the full external ID in `record` node.

```xml
<record id="acs_hms.group_hms_jr_doctor" model="res.groups">
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(3, ref('acs_hms.group_hms_nurse'))]"/>
</group>
```

Comment: Do you mean that I just need to add the module name before id?

Comment: Among the other things yes. Don't forget the dependency and don't override every field of that group, if you wish to change just one like `implied_ids`.

Comment: I tried above code, but still, it doesn't affect the group on updating module and even -u all option.

Comment: Yes i didn't read your requirement fully, to delete a relation you have to use "magic number" `3` in this case. I've changed my code.

Comment: This code deletes acs_hms.group_hms_jr_doctor group from implieds_ids of base group or the acs_hms.group_hms_nurse group?. I got confused about it.

Comment: The nurse group.

Comment: I applyed `<record id="acs_hms.group_hms_jr_doctor" model="res.groups">
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(3, ref('acs_hms.group_hms_jr_doctor'))]"/>
    </record>` but still the base group is not overriding. I use this command to update sever: `./odoo-bin --addons-path='addons, ../hms, ../acs-hms, ../12.e' --xmlrpc-port=9000 -d db_hms -u all`

Comment: What do you mean by the base group is not overriding?

Comment: I mean the changes are not applied even after using that command. I even found this[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340375/how-to-remove-implied-ids-from-group-in-odoo] and tried this code but still no effect.`<record id="acs_hms.group_hms_jr_doctor" model="res.groups">
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('acs_hms.group_hms_receptionist'))]"/>
        <field name="users" eval="[(3, ref('base.user_root')), (4, ref('base.user_admin'))]"/>
    </record>`

Comment: You could also try with `[(6, 0, ref('acs_hms.group_hms_receptionist'))]` which should reset the relations to only one -> receptionist.